# Sorting Algorithms with constraints on Array

Tags: algorithm, sorting, big-o

I am trying to come up with an algorithm that sorts and array A in O(nlog(logn)) time.
Where A[0...n-1] with the property A[i] >= A[i-j] for all j >= log(n).

So far I have thought to partition A into blocks that are each logn size.

Then I think that the first block will be be strightly smaller then blocks that come after it?

I think I'm missing part of it.

Comment: A[log(n)-1] could be larger than A[log(n)+1], but they are in different blocks, so the first block is not smaller than other blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Tree Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_sort)  would be an option here.  You start at the left end of your array and feed elements into the tree.  Whenever your tree has more than log(n) elements you take the smallest element out, because you know for sure that all subsequent elements are larger, and put it back into the sorted array.  This way the tree size is always log(n), and the cost of a tree operation is log(log(n)).  In fact you only need the operations (1)insert random element and (2) remove smallest element, so you don't need necessarily a tree, but any sort of [priority queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) would do for that purpose.  This way both average and worst-case performance meet your requirements.

Comment: @amit: You can definitely use this algorithm to sort all `n` elements. I also think that this is a very good algorithm to do it (especially when implemented with a fast prioqueue) and very fast in practice and very cache-efficient as well. Mind to share your thoughts on a better algorithm to do it?

Comment: Very nice answer. I was asked this question in a Google interview and this is the answer they were looking for :) Not sure if this has anything to say